# ¿como soluciono este error de mi placa ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

tengo la siguiente placa ESP32:
[image: es una placa esp32 wroom con entrada tipo C]

al intentar subirle codigo desde arduinoIDE me sale este error:
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
(POR FAVOR AYUDA NO SE QUE HACER)

Comment: Verificaste la lista de posibles causas que da esa misma página. ???? (A mi una vez me pasó que era el cable el malo)

Comment: ya probe 2 cables y si he visto mil tutoriales o posibles soluciones y nada funciona